# Solve exponential equation with constant term.

Tags: exponential-function

Is there an analytical solution to an equation of the form $a e^{(\alpha + i \beta) x} - b e^{(\alpha - i \beta) x} + c = 0$? How can we solve such an equation to $x$?

EDIT 1:
Thanks for your patience with me. I tried it based on your hint in Matlab with the following code:

```
a = 5.6;
b = -12.6;
c = 18.9;
alpha = 2.5;
beta = 3.3;

r = (alpha+1j*beta)/(alpha-1j*beta);
A = a/b;
C = c/b;
y = C;
for n = 1:100
  derivative = (n*r)*C^((n*r)-1);
  y = y + ((A^n)/(factorial(n)))*derivative;
end;

y
y_correct = fsolve(@(y)(a*y^r - b*y + c), 1)
```

However, this yields $y = -1.497762285457014e+00 + 1.248026585918367e-02i$ and $y_{correct} = -1.517484388747081e+00 + 8.391487021758234e-03i$.
When I check with

```
A*y^r + C - y
```

the result is not 0, so clearly there is an error here somewhere.

EDIT 2:
found the problem:

```
a = 5.6;
b = -12.6;
c = 18.9;
alpha = 2.5;
beta = 3.3;

r = (alpha+1j*beta)/(alpha-1j*beta);
A = a/b;
C = c/b;
y = C;
for n = 1:100
  if n == 1
    derivative = C^r;
  else
    derivative = (n*r)*C^((n*r)-1);
  endif;
  y = y + ((A^n)/(factorial(n)))*derivative;
end;
```

works good!

EDIT 3:
There was still an error in the derivative. I fixed it and wrote an answer.

Comment: You can substitute $y=e^{(\alpha-i\beta)x}$ and use [series solution for general trinomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. However I've try to substitute as you recommend, ending up in $a e^{(\alpha + j \beta) x} - b y + c = 0$. $x$ remains in the equation and I'm still lost.

Comment: You should get $e^x=y^\frac1{\alpha-i\beta}$, so $a y^\frac{\alpha+i\beta}{\alpha-i\beta}-by+c=0$. Also, are you looking for all complex solutions or just one?

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that helps!

Comment: Ok, I tried to apply the stuff from your link to my problem, however did not succeed. Might need a little primer to get things in the right way.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you can [add more details](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), like your attempts to solve the equation. Then, I can write an answer.

Comment: For one solution, you can try [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem): $Ay^r+C=y\implies y=C+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!} \left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}w^{nr}\right|_{w=C}$. There is a method to get multiple complex solutions, but it is a little more work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$
Let $r=\alpha+\beta i,A=\frac ab,B=\frac ca$:

$$a e^{rz}-be^{\bar rz}+c=0\iff A e^{(r-\bar r)z}+B e^{-\bar rz}=1$$

and substitute like in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial?_gl=1*k9e7md*_ga*OTgzOTk0ODY2LjE2ODU3OTE0ODk.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4NjUyOTgyMi42MC4xLjE2ODY1MzIyODYuMC4wLjA.):

$$B(e^z)^{-\bar r}=w,\ln(e^z)=-\frac{\ln\left(\frac wB\right)}{\bar r}-\frac{2\pi i k}{\bar r}\implies e^z=e^{-\frac{2\pi i k}{\bar r}}\left(\frac w B\right)^{-\frac1{\bar r}}$$

to get:

$$w=1-Ae^{2\pi i k(1-\sgn^2(r))}B^{\sgn^2(r)-1}w^{1-\sgn^2(r)}=1-pw^v$$

Using [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) and [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html):

$$e^\frac{2\pi i k}{\bar r}e^z=\left(\frac1B\right)^{-\frac1{\bar r}}-\frac{B^\frac 1{\bar r}}{\bar r}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-p)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\left(w^{vn}\frac d{dt}\left(\frac tB\right)^{-\frac1{\bar r}}\right)=B^\frac1{\bar r}-\frac{B^{\frac 1{\bar r}}}{\bar r}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-p)^n}{n!}\left(vn-\frac1{\bar r}-1\right)^{(n-1)}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+-4+z%5E-0.8%2B1-1%2F3+4%5E0.4+z%5E%28-0.8*0.4%29) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2F4%29%5E%28-1%2F0.8%29-4%5E%281%2F0.8%29%2F0.8+sum%5B%28-1%2F3%29%5En%2Fn%21+factorialpower%28%280.4+n+-+1+-+1%2F0.8%29%2C+-1+%2B+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C8%7D%5D%2Cw%3D1.0) is a solution to $B y^{-\bar r}=1-p (B y^{-\bar r})^v$

Comment: To be updated with more details

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Tyma Gaidash, I came up with this solution:

```
clear all; close all;

format long;

a = 5.6;
b = -12.6;
c = 18.9;
alpha = 2.5;
beta = 3.3;

r = (alpha+1j*beta)/(alpha-1j*beta);
A = a/b;
C = c/b;
y = C;
for n = 1:100
  derivative = C^((n*r) - (n-1));
  for j = 1:(n-1)
    derivative = derivative * ((n*r) - (1-j));
  end;
  y = y + ((A^n)/(factorial(n)))*derivative;
end;

y
y_correct = fsolve(@(y)(a*y^r - b*y + c), 1)
A*y^r + C - y
```